# Mirroring the image in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Hi I want to convert normal image into mirror i.e flop effect in BLACKBERRY app.I have tried this code but unable too convert...Is there anyone to help me to do this...

If you have a different logic to do this please share..

```
public Bitmap changetoFlopEffect(Bitmap bitmap){

     int[] argb = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
     int[] newargb =new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
     int  length=bitmap.getWidth();

     bitmap.getARGB(argb, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

     for(int i=0;i<=bitmap.getHeight();i++)
     {
         for(int j=bitmap.getWidth(),k=0;j>0;j--)
         {
                //newargb[k]=argb[j];
                int swap=argb[j];
                newargb[k]=swap;
                k++;
         }
     }  
      bitmap.setARGB(newargb,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
     return bitmap;       
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with this? I mean were some pixels mirrored? Post some images of what you got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your corner conditions seem wrong and the pixels you swipe are from the first row only. Try this:

```
public Bitmap changetoFlopEffect(Bitmap bitmap){

 int[] argb = new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
 int[] newargb =new int[bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight()];
 int  length=bitmap.getWidth();
 int newIndex = 0;

 bitmap.getARGB(argb, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

 for (int i = 0; i < bitmap.getHeight(); i++)
   for (int j = bitmap.getWidth()-1; j >= 0 ; j--){
    newargb[newIndex] = argb[i * bitmap.getWidth() + j];
    newIndex++;
   }  
  bitmap.setARGB(newargb,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
 return bitmap;       
}
```

Comment: I had resolved this before your reply....But your reply output is better than me. so thanks for that......Can you help me to negative and monochrome the image...    reply

Comment: I used ImageEffectControll interface from javax.microedition.amms.control.imageeffect.                       I found this on this link http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/amms/control/imageeffect/ImageEffectControl.html
This is for monochrom and negative effects..
If You have solution to this please Share your logic please.

Comment: reply on my this thread--How to apply monochrome and negative effect on image in Blackberry application.